# How do I convert a python list to simple YAML?

Tags: python, yaml

My lists are very small and I can do these by hand, but I'm looking for the right way to do this programmatically.  I have this as a test:

```
import yaml

a = ['item 1','item 2','item 3','item 4']
yaml.dump(a)
```

which give me this:

```
'[item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4]\n'
```

when what I want is simple YAML output like this:

```
---
- item 1
- item 2
- item 3
- item 4
```

Would this need to be in a `dict` structure, with values, but somehow without keys?  Not quite sure how to proceed here.  Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which YAML library for Python do you use?

Comment: Running Python 2.7 and PyYAML==3.11

Comment: You can give a try to this :  yaml.dump([1,2,3], explicit_start=True)

Comment: That seems to get me a bit closer with `'--- [item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4]\n'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to set the following paramters to the dump function:

- `explicit_start=True` for the `---` at the beginning of the output.
- `default_flow_style=False` to print the items separated in each line.

```
import yaml

a = ['item 1','item 2','item 3','item 4']
yaml.dump(a, explicit_start=True, default_flow_style=False)
```

will give you

`'---\n- item 1\n- item 2\n- item 3\n- item 4\n'`

if you `print` the output, you get

```
---
- item 1
- item 2
- item 3
- item 4
```

Comment: Sebastian Stigler - brilliant! Confirmed in my current session. Much appreciated!!

Comment: This also would have been helpful had I found it first.  Posting the link to some of the yaml.dump() parameters:  https://dpinte.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/pyaml-dump-option/